# Adding react-svg-loader to webpack

Tags: svg, webpack

I want to use react-svg-loader to import and use some svg assets I have for my app. You can find my webpack config below. The problem, however, is that I am also using some file loaders for svg files. These are needed because parts of my app are importing icons from font awesome, e.g. `<i className="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true" />`. So I can get the react-svg-loader working by stop having my file loader look for svg files, but then a lot of the icons on my app won't render. If I don't do this then my webpack will fail to build, saying things like:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/react-svg-loader/lib/loader.js):
NonErrorEmittedError: (Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) Error in parsing SVG: Non-whitespace before first tag.
```

So how can I resolve these two conflicts? Thanks.

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

const DIST_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "dist");
const SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "src");

const config = {
  entry: [
    "babel-polyfill",
    `${SRC_DIR}/app/index.js`,
    `${SRC_DIR}/app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss`,
    `${SRC_DIR}/app/components/index.scss`,
    "font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss",
    "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css",
    "rc-time-picker/assets/index.css",
    "react-circular-progressbar/dist/styles.css",
    "@trendmicro/react-toggle-switch/dist/react-toggle-switch.css",
  ],
  output: {
    path: `${DIST_DIR}/app/`,
    filename: "bundle.js",
    publicPath: "/app/"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "babel-loader"
          },
          {
            loader: "react-svg-loader",
            options: {
              jsx: true
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        enforce: "pre",
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "eslint-loader",
        options: {
          failOnWarning: false,
          failOnError: true
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: SRC_DIR,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'stage-2']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
        loaders: ['file-loader?context=src/images&name=images/[path][name].[ext]', {
          loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
          query: {
            mozjpeg: {
              progressive: true,
            },
            gifsicle: {
              interlaced: false,
            },
            optipng: {
              optimizationLevel: 7,
            },
            pngquant: {
              quality: '75-90',
              speed: 3,
            },
          },
        }],
        exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules"),
        include: __dirname,
      },
      {
        test: /\.woff2?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        // loader: "url?limit=10000"
        use: "url-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?[\s\S]+)?$/,
        use: 'file-loader'
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "application.css"
    }),
  ]
};

module.exports = config;
```

Answer (score 7):

I had similar issues, while trying to load SVG's with react-svg-loader, but Font Awesome SVG's with file-loader. This was the config that I used to solve that problem:

```
  {
    test: /\.svg$/,
    exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'font-awesome'),
    use: ['babel-loader', 'react-svg-loader'],
  },
  {
    test: /\.svg$/,
    include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'font-awesome'),
    use: [{
      loader: 'file-loader',
      options: {
        jsx: true,
      },
    }],
  },
```

If your webpack config is not in the root, correct the exclude/include paths accordingly!

Note that you have multiple rules for SVG's in your webpack config, play with include/excludes to make them all work for your case.

Comment: {
    test: /\.svg$/,
    exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'font-awesome'),
    use: ['babel-loader', 'react-svg-loader'],
  },   This line solved my issue. Very strange. Would be nice to know the exact reason. My webpack.config is in the root. Thanks for sharing.